# Controlling media on one android phone from another

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm building a custom device. It runs android(rooted/configurable). 
What I want to do is this: when my device is paired to your phone, it can accept/reject calls, control music(Volume +/-, next song, play/pause etc).
I don't want the audio. The audio plays from your phone itself. I just want to control the calls and the music. I have been reading up a lot on Bluetooth and profiles. And I'm not sure if there is a right one out there for me. Also it would be more helpful, if i can do all these functions without an app. That is i just pair the devices and they work. Hoping someone can help me whit this.

Comment: Think that implementation is easy for music control. Your device can act as a HID keyboard and have all required keys. [link](https://source.android.com/devices/input/keyboard-devices). Not sure about phone call, need to see how wired headset buttons processing implemented. You can try to implement modified client for Headset/Handsfree Bluetooth profile which will fail SCO connection establishement but not sure about AG side system behavior after SCO be failed.

Comment: @hank, ill try this out. thanks